# Finding location of AppVeyor built artifact for post_build action

Tags: appveyor

I have had AppVeyor building nuget packages and deploying them for me, but now I am trying to do something `post_build` to the nuget package.

So basically, I have:

```
build:
  project: XmlRpcCore.sln
  parallel: true
  verbosity: minimal
  publish_nuget: true
  publish_nuget_symbols: false
```

as well as:

```
deploy:
  - provider: NuGet
    name: nuget_release
    api_key:
      secure: MJz3DvmtiuNK6IVsPbxR3gWiSCnhKqm6tmPsjdRDgwGx9L2PQSSZ1eE7YS8dkZhx
    skip_symbols: true
    on:
      appveyor_repo_tag: true
```

and so forth and everything works fine.

Now, my problem comes in trying to find the nuget package for processing in `post_build` after the `build` step. It doesn't reside in `APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER`. I see in output:

```
Successfully created package 'C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\py7750yjd6\XmlRpcCore.3.1.0.62.nupkg'.
```

but I don't see any environment variables to help me out with that path so I can call a powershell command in `post_build` before `deploy` like so:

```
after_build:
 - ps: dir
 - ps: MagicCmd -InputPath "$env:<what might go here?>\XmlRpcCore.$env:TAG_VERSION.nuget"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information about generated artifacts is available in PowerShell session: https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/#getting-information-about-uploaded-artifacts

You can have a simple PowerShell script in `before_deploy` section analyzing that hash and putting desired value into environment variable, for example, to get the path of first generated artifact:

```
before_deploy:
- ps: |
    foreach ($artifactName in $artifacts.keys) {
      $env:packagePath = $artifacts[$artifactName].path
      break
    }
- 'echo This is the path: %packagePath%'
```